# Representation theory of $SU(2)$: Left-Right symmetric models

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, group-theory, representation-theory, higgs

My question concerns the following excerpt of the article [A Fermionic bi-Doublet Effective Field Theory for Dark Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10916):

[image]

I do not understand how the action of $SU_L(2) \times SU_R(2)$ on $Mat^{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ is supposed to be $(U_L,U_R).\mathscr{D} = U_L \mathscr{D} U_R$ as this is neither a left nor a right action. I would instead expect the correct action to be something like $(U_L,U_R).\mathscr{D} = U_L \mathscr{D} U_R^\dagger$, which would be a left action. This would also be more consistent with the electric charges assigned to the components of $\mathscr{D}$ because then the third component of the spin $I_3^L + I_3^R$ would be given by:

$S_3 \mathscr{D} = -i \partial_t|_{t=0} [(\exp(\frac{i}{2} \sigma_3) , \exp(\frac{i}{2} \sigma_3) ).\mathscr{D}] = \frac{1}{2} [\sigma_3,\mathscr{D}]$

which leads to  $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ and  $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ having $z$-spin 0,  $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ having spin 1 and $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ having spin -1 as indicated by the superscripts in equation 2.5 (see screen shot above).

As I am quite new to the whole topic, I am  uncertain about the validity of my arguments and would be grateful if you could either confirm them or explain to me the notation used in the paper quoted.

Comment: Have you studied and understood ref [8]?

Comment: Isn't ref [8] postulating exactly the transformation behaviour that I proposed i.e. $(U_L, U_R).D = U_L D U_R^\dagger$ instead of $(U_L, U_R).D = U_L D U_R$?

Comment: ? Are you talking about (3.3) of [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(80)90214-X)? what is *D*? What are *A,B*? Above, $\mathscr{D}$ (2.5) has the same transformation properties and charge assignments as (2.3).

Comment: Sorry for the misleading notation, I removed the $A$,$B$ and $D$ now and replaced them with a notation more consistent with the one used in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot decipher your peculiar notes of your understanding, but the paper appears straightforward.

Defining $U_L=\exp (i\vec \tau \cdot \vec \theta),\qquad  U_R=\exp (i\vec \tau \cdot \vec \phi)$, you may observe
$$
\mathcal{ H}=  \begin{bmatrix} H^+\\ H^0 \\ \end{bmatrix},  ~~~\tilde{\mathcal{ H}}=-i\tau_2  \mathcal{ H}^*= \begin{bmatrix}- H^0\\ H^- \\ \end{bmatrix} ~~~\leadsto \\
\mathscr{H}=[\tilde{\mathcal{ H}} ,  \mathcal{ H} ],
$$
so that,
$$
\mathcal{ H} \to U_L \mathcal{ H} , \qquad \tilde{\mathcal{ H}} \to U_L \tilde{\mathcal{ H}} ~~~\implies \\ 
\mathscr{H}\to U_L \mathscr{H}. 
$$

But also
$$
  [ -H^{0~*}, H^+] \to [-H^{0~*}, H^+] U_R, \qquad   [ H^{ -}, H^0]\to [ H^{ -}, H^0] U_R   \implies \\ \mathscr{H}\to  \mathscr{H} U_R.
$$

You are told $\mathscr{D}$ transforms exactly the same way, so that
$\operatorname{Tr} \mathscr{H}^\dagger \mathscr{D}= \operatorname{Tr} \mathscr{D}\mathscr{H}^\dagger $ is an invariant under both $U_L$ and $U_R$.

---

*NB elicited by the comments*

As you have discovered, people switch conventions at the drop of a hat, and so the paper you are discussing has very different ones (check the v.e.v. !) from those of the ur-reference [8]. (Frankly, Longhitano's paper is superior.) So the right action need not have a dagger on it, since you never take the vector diagonal product of the the two isospins.

To help you review the conventional picture, in the SM, for ultimately degenerate *u,d* quarks, you'd have the Yukawa terms, L-R invariant,  present as
$$[u_L^\dagger, d_L^\dagger]\mathscr{H}   \begin{bmatrix}  -u_R\\  d_R \\ \end{bmatrix}.     $$

So the rightmost, R-spinor doublet transforms  through $U_R^\dagger$, not  $U_R$ !

Note each of the four terms of the above dot product is electrically natural.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The assignments of the isospin is still puzzling me though. For example, I would think that if you do not have the dagger for $U_R$, then $ M = 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ should have $I_3^L$ eigenvalue of $1/2$ as $ \frac{1}{2} \sigma_3 M = \frac{1}{2}$ but also $I_3^R$ eigenvalue of $1/2$ since  $M \frac{1}{2} \sigma_3  = \frac{1}{2}$. But then the charge of the particle would be $1$ instead of $0$.

Comment: (if on the other hand we act on the right with $U_R^\dagger$ then the sign of $I_3^R$ is flipped, leading to results consistent with the assertion that $M$ corresponds to a state with charge $0$.)

Comment: As I suggested, I have ***no*** idea what your mysterious symbols and implications are. I am just fixing and parsing out the basic facts of the L-R construction.

Comment: Well my problem is that in the end $H^{+,0,-}$ are supposed to have charge $Q = I_3^R + I_3^L$ of $1,0$ and $-1$. I think that I understand how this arises in [8] for example in the construction of $\Phi$ (eq. 2.2). But my reasoning doesn't work in the construction that I asked about i.e. with the transformation $H \rightarrow U_L H U_R$ instead of $U_L H U_R^\dagger$. So if you could explain to me how the correct charges arise here or recommend some literature to me, this would help a lot!

Comment: Oh, that's a convention! θ and φ are completely independent, so my and the paper's φ, for simplicity, are the opposite of [8]'s φ. You may stick a minus sign in the definitions above. L and R actions are characterized by the *location* of the unitary matrices, not their angles!

Comment: Ah! Thank you, this is the information that I was missing.